# Also Emit Values from retry and catch

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have simple flow structure as below. Most of the logic happen in `use_case`. Use_case emits these values to `viewmodel`.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

sealed class Resource<out T:Any>{
    data class Success<out T:Any> (val data:T):Resource<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception):Resource<Nothing>()
    data class Loading(val message:String):Resource<Nothing>()
}


fun myUseCase() = flowOf(
Resource.Loading("Loading..."),
Resource.Loading("Loading..."),
Resource.Error(Exception("Error_Occured")))
    .onEach { 
        when (it) {
            is Resource.Error -> {
                throw it.exception
            }
            is Resource.Loading -> {}
            is Resource.Success -> {}
        }
    }.retry(1, {
        println("retrying...")
        true
    })
    .catch { 
        println("catch error... $it")
    }
    

fun myViewModel() = runBlocking<Unit> {
        myUseCase()
        .collect {
            println("Result $it")
        } 
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit>  {
    myViewModel()
}
```

But in case of `catch` and `retry` I can't send current resource to viewmodel.
This is what i want to achieve.

```
.retry(1, {
        Resource.Loading("retrying...")  => also emit this resource
        println("retrying...")
        true
    })
    .catch { 
        Resource.Error(Exception("finished with error"))  => also emit this resource
        println("catch error... $it")
    }
```

Is it possible?

Edit

it is possible to emit from catch but i couldnt find out how to emit from retry.

```
    .catch { 
        emit(Resource.Error(Exception("finished with error")))
    }
```

Comment: I think you example is overly simplified.  It seems like the UseCase in reality would be acting upon a flow provided by another resource.  The UseCase could return a hot flow (SharedFlow or StateFlow) and as it evaluates emitted values from the other resource it can map and emit to the hot flow at its discression.